# Marker Google map Does not display sometimes

Tags: jquery

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                draggable:true
            });

        marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
        }));

        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: can you explain better? have you any error in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `loadSpots()` at the end of `initializeMaps()`, otherwise it may happen that  the `map` will be accessed before it's initialized.